# How to add/remove characters inside TextField?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a Room database with a table that holds users. Each user has an ID and a name. My goal is to change the name of the user based on the ID. Here is what I have tried.

I have an UsersScreen that contains a LazyColumn where I display all users. It works fine. Each row is represented by a user. On user click, I navigate forward to UpdateUserNameScreen by passing the ID of the user. In this screen I'm calling `getUser(id)` function to return the desired user. Here is my code:

```
fun UpdateUserNameScreen(
    userId: Int,
    viewModel: UserViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    var name by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            //TopBar content
        },
        content = {
            viewModel.getUser(userId) //Get the user.

            TextField(
                value = viewModel.userState.value.name, //Set user name.
                onValueChange = { name = it },
            )
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    val user = User(userId, name)
                    viewModel.updateUser(user)
                    navController.popBackStack()
                }
            ) {
                Text("Save")
            }
        }
    )
}
```

When I open this screen, I see the name of the user added in the TextField, which is fine. However, when I try to add change the name, no character can be added or deleted. How can change the name of the user inside the TextField?

Comment: you read from `viewModel.userState.value.name` and update `title`, which is not presented in your code at all. Make sure that `onValueChange` will update value in `viewModel.userState.value.name`

Comment: @PylypDukhov Thanks for commenting. Actually it was a typo. It should have been `onValueChange = { name = it }`, as in my updated code.  And above in the code I have `var name by remember { mutableStateOf("") }`. Do I still need to do the same thing?

Comment: @PylypDukhov I have changed in the VM the object to `val userState = mutableStateOf(User(0, ""))` and inside the Screen `onValueChange = { viewModel.userState.value.name = it }`, and still have the same behaviour. Nothing is added in the TextField. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `TextField` trigger `onValueChange` it's expected that you modify value passed into `value`.

If you want to edit your view model property, you can do something like this, expecting `User` to be a data class:

```
onValueChange = { viewModel.userState.value = viewModel.userState.value.copy(name = it) },
```

Usually you don't wanna edit view model state directly, you can create a setter like this:

```
// view model
var userState by mutableStateOf(User(0, ""))
    private set

fun updateUserName(name: String) {
    userState = userState.copy(name = name)
    // e.g. add validation
}
// view
onValueChange = viewModel::updateUserName
```

---

An other option is that you actually wanna edit a local variable, which should be initialized with user name - so you can then make a request with new name and only update user value when request succeed.

In this case you can initialize `name` with user name and use `name` both for `value` and `setValue`:

```
class VM: ViewModel() {
    var userState by mutableStateOf(User(0, ""))
        private set
}

@Composable
fun TestScreen() {
    val viewModel = viewModel<VM>()
    val (name, setName) = remember(viewModel.userState.name) { mutableStateOf(viewModel.userState.name) }
    TextField(
        value = name,
        onValueChange = setName
    )
}
```

Comment: If I define in the VM, `var userState by mutableStateOf(User(0, ""))`, to be able to access the name, it should be `remember(viewModel.userState.name)`, without value. Doing that change, if I use your last solution, when setting `onValueChange = setName`, Android Studio is complaining with `The expression is unused -> val setName: (String) → Unit.`

Comment: @JoanP. I've updated the second part of my answer, this builds fine to me

Comment: Ok, thank you for that. I'll try it right now, and I'll provide a feed-back.

Comment: Yes, it compiles fine now. The single problem left, is that Android Studio is complaining with `The expression is unused -> val setName: (String) → Unit`. Basically nothing is added or removed to the `TextField` when typing. Any idea why?

Comment: That's the same in the case of using `updateUserName` inside the VM.

Comment: @JoanP. The code from the second part of the answer works to me, show how you've implemented in your case. You can use [gist](https://gist.github.com)